# Laravel 5.1 firstOrNew with relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I use `firstOrNew` method with Laravel relationships.

I have the following relationship:

```
/**
 * The rows that belong to the timesheet.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function rowTimesheet()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Timesheet\RowTimesheet');
}
```

I am trying to create a new row for the timesheet in the database using the following.  I don't get any errors, but the row doesn't get inserted.

Any ideas?

```
/**
 * Create timesheet rows.
 *
 * @param $id
 * @param $row
 */
public function createTimesheetRow($id, $row) 
{
    return $this->timesheet->find($id)->rowTimesheet()->firstOrNew($row);
}
```

Comment: tried `->save()` after `->firstOrNew($row)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello about `firstOrNew`

> model returned by firstOrNew has not yet been persisted to the database. You will need to call save manually to persist it

so you can try

```
public function createTimesheetRow($id, $row) 
{
    return $this->timesheet->find($id)->rowTimesheet()->firstOrCreate($row);
}
```

or

```
public function createTimesheetRow($id, $row) 
{
    $row = $this->timesheet->find($id)->rowTimesheet()->firstOrNew($row);
    return $row->save();
}
```

more info you can read in [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)